# Access to HttpConduit before loading WSDL on CXF Dynamic Client

Tags: wsdl, cxf, http-conduit

Before loading WSDL from https URL for my dynamic client I need to set appropriate configuration on [HttpConduit](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/HTTPConduit.html) to avoid all SSL errors. According to [docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-ConfiguringSSLSupport%20ConfiguringSSLSupport) we could hardcode conduit but not sure to do it programmatically. Is there way I could get hold of HttpConduit before creating `Client` object on `DynamicClientFactory`?

```
JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance();

//Need to get HttpConduit here before the client is created, how?
Client client = dcf.createClient(wsdlUri);

// Can access http conduit only after client is created
HTTPConduit conduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
```

Comment: It doesn't matter when you set ```HttpConduit``` It is going to be used when client is being used. so you can set it after creation of client also.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get of hold [HttpConduit](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/HTTPConduit.html) and customize the http(s) configuration is through [HTTPConduitConfigurer](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/transport/http/HTTPConduitConfigurer.html). Below code snippet shows how it can be done.

```
Bus bus = CXFBusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
bus.setExtension(new HTTPConduitConfigurer() {

    @Override
    public void configure(String name, String address, HTTPConduit conduit) {
        //set conduit parameters ...

        // ex. disable host name verification
        TLSClientParameters clientParameters = new TLSClientParameters();
        clientParameters.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });
        conduit.setTlsClientParameters(clientParameters);
    }
}, HTTPConduitConfigurer.class);

JaxWsDynamicClientFactory dcf = JaxWsDynamicClientFactory.newInstance(bus);
Client client = dcf.createClient(wsdlUri);
```